# Triple Join in Django

Tags: sql, django, join

This is the first time I've had a question that I couldn't find an answer to within an hour of searching here, so this is the first time I've had to post:

How do I do a triple join in Django?  This is a minimal version of what I already have:

```
class A(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(X)
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y)

class B(models.Model):
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y, related_name="Bs")
    z = models.ForeignKey(Z)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class C(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(X)
    z = models.ForeignKey(Z)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def updateA():
    as = A.objects.all()
    for a in as:
        for b in a.y.Bs:
            if b.value <= C.objects.get(x=a.x, z=b.z).value:
                <a.stuff = b.stuff>
```

What I really want is a triple join between tables A, B, and C,
where a.x=c.x, a.y=b.y, b.z=c.z, AND b.value <= c.value,
though I don't care about c after validating b.value <= c.value.

Is there a way in Django to do more of this work in the database?

The problem I have is that Django seems to inherently focus on
two-way joins, and I don't see how to do a three-way join.

Then again, I didn't know any Django or Python 6 weeks ago,
so I'm new to this framework and don't know the more advanced tricks.

Comment: Why do you make it extra hard for would be helpers with this x,y,a,b nonsense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the following, based on extra, as suggested by NeErAj KuMaR, though I had to fix up a few things first (adding _id to foreign keys, putting variable names in "" to protect uppercase letter, and using myapp_a instead of selecting another copy of table A as renaming it as t1).  Basically, we select out the new value from table t2 via 'select', do a join over all three tables, enforce the constraints, and end up with a list of As that need to be updated:

```
    as = A.objects.all().extra(select={'nextY_id' : 't2."nextY_id"'}, tables=['"myapp_b" AS "t2"', '"myapp_c" AS "t3"'], where=['t2.deleted = false AND t2.minimum <= t3."baseValue" AND myapp_a."x_id"=t3."x_id" AND myapp_a."y_id"=t2."y_id" AND t2."z_id"=t3."z_id"']).only('x_id','y_id').distinct('id') # extra does not quote to protect uppercase letters.

    for a in as:
        f(a.x_id, a.y_id, oldValue=True)
        a.y_id = a.nextY_id # a.y_id is updated, a.y is not.
        f(a.x_id, a.y_id)
        a.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
A.objects.all().extra(tables=['"table_a" AS "t1"', '"table_b" AS "t2"', '"table_c" AS "t3"'], where=['t1.x=t3.x AND t1.y=t2.y AND t2.z=t3.z AND t2.value <= t3.value'])
```

Replce `'table'` string with **app name** (lowercase) from these strings in above query `'table_a','table_b','table_c'`  to your app name

Comment: Issues with this solution:

1) You can't compare t1.x and t3.x directly.  You need t1.x_id and t3.x_id

2) That doesn't quite work, since you want the original table as t1, not the supplemental, so you want x_id = t3.x_id

3) That doesn't quite work, since x_id is ambiguous, because it exists in both tables.

4) If instead of x_id, we had xX_id, that would fail because django would convert it xx_id, but it would be xX_id in the database, resulting in xx_id column not found, hint: did you mean xX_id?

Comment: Blocking Bug: This does not work if any of your column names contain a capital letter.

Answer (score -3):

Django's ORM is not well suited to complex data models or query expressions.  You can spend much more effort trying to get something done with Django than it would take to write a bit of SQL to do it.  You can take advantage of Django's forms and validation routines without using Djanogo's ORM at all.  If you have anything but a simple data model and you already know SQL, you might prefer that approach.